# Gastby build --prefix-path for github pages not working properly

Tags: path, github-pages

I am trying to build my Gatsby project to host it on github pages and I am follwing [the gastby guidelines](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/previews-deploys-hosting/how-gatsby-works-with-github-pages/) but the --prefix-path is not working for assets like common.js , framework.js ,...

All path that don't have this prefix  will end up returning a 404. So I've tried to also add assetPrefix, which does add a prefix to these asset urls but breaks the regular routing.

For example: 
When navigating to `https://username.github.io/reponame/hello_world` the window location will be adjusted to `https://username.github.io/hello_world`. So this seems like a wrong approach.

This is my config file:

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
  pathPrefix: "/reponame",
  // basePath: "/reponame",
})

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `gastby`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@yondr`,
    siteUrl: `my_github_url.com/reponame`,
  },
  assetPrefix: "/reponame",


  ...
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution:

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})

module.exports = {
  ...
  pathPrefix: process.env.PATH_PREFIX || "/",
  ...
}
```